# Reading / Extracting Data from Databricks Database (hive_metastore ) with PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am trying to read in data from Databricks Hive_Metastore with PySpark. In screenshot below, I am trying to read in the table called 'trips' which is located in the database `nyctaxi`.

Typically if this table was located on a AzureSQL server I was use code like the following:

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
    .option("url", jdbcUrl)\
    .option("dbtable", tableName)\
    .load()
```

Or if the table was in the ADLS I would use code similar to the following:

```
df = spark.read.csv("adl://mylake.azuredatalakestore.net/tableName.csv",header=True)
```

Can some let me know how I would read in the table using PySpark from Databricks Database below:

[image]

The additional screenshot my also help

[image]

Ok, I've just realized that I think I should be asking how to read tables from "samples" meta_store.

In any case I would like help reading in the "trips" table from the `nyctaxi` database please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `samples` catalog can be accessed in using `spark.table("catalog.schema.table")`.

So you should be able to access the table using:

```py
df = spark.table("samples.nyctaxi.trips")
```

Note also if you are working direct in databricks notebooks, the spark session is already available as `spark` - no need to get or create.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check if you have HiveSupport Enabled in your Spark Session.
You can enable this by

```py
spark = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .appName("HiveTest") \
            .enableHiveSupport() \
            .getOrCreate()
```

To verify you can use

```py
spark.sql("show databases").show()
# This should show you all your hive metastore databases as in Image shared

# To read data in df

df = spark.sql("select * from db_name.table_name")
df.show()
```

In case of error you will have to check for hive.metastore properties configs for databricks environment according to their documentations.

Comment: Hi @glory9211, thanks for reaching out. I will try your suggestion. In the meantime, is there not a way of reading / loading the data in using regular pyspark e.g. df = spark.read.csv("pathtotable",header=True).load() ?

Comment: Hi @glory9211, I'm getting the NameError: name 'SparkSession' is not defined

Comment: Hi @glory9211, I fixed the NameError with ```from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()```

Comment: when I execute ```spark.sql("show databases").show()``` it just shows the 'default' database

Comment: In the image you have two dropdowns. "hive_metastore" and "samples". Can you check under hive_metastore if there is a default db only. If yes then you can create a new one under it and then see if the changes reflect in a new spark instance. If this works then it means your configs are pointing to 'hive_metastore' instead of 'sample'

Comment: Ans to first comment: Hive Metastore doesn't actually have the data stored in it. It only has information about the actual data (location, columns, partitions etc. ). If you can get the location of files for the hive table and the format you can try and read the data i.e. ```df = spark.read.format('your_format').load('the path according to hive metastore')```

Comment: Hi @glory9211, I have another database under hive_metastore and I can see the database. That is fine for now, because our Production environment has all databases under hive_metastore, so thank you for that. If you could let me know why I can't use the df =spark.read.format in PySpark as I showed using sample read of database in my question. (I know my sample shows me reading from a database with jdbc format. But I would just like know what would be the equivalent in PySpark when reading from hive_metastore database. I hope I'm making sense

Comment: Hi @glory9211, you answered my question as I was writing. You mentioned ```spark.sql("show databases").show()```

Comment: So, if I do ```df = spark.sql("select * from db_name.table_name")``` is that effectively as good as reading the files from its actual location?